# AWS mobile analytics KIPs API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mobile-analytics

I need  to call aws mobile analytics KIP's api (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/drs-querying-kpis-lifetime-count.html) but I am stuck with how headers for this request should be passed.
I have gone through their api reference.

What is the header format for calling this api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of my raw Headers for one of my requests:

```
Host: mobileanalytics.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: application/hal+json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Amz-Date: 20161024T192952Z
X-Amz-Security-Token: INSERT_SECURITY_TOKEN
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=INSERT_CREDENTIAL/20161024/us-east-1/mobileanalytics/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=INSERT_SIGNATURE
Connection: keep-alive
```

Be sure to include the `Accept` header:

```
Accept: application/hal+json
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please consider post the headers as text/code as it's much easier to reuse / search them that way.

Comment: Updated with the text